# Reverberate clean sound

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

i have a clean sound sample as a wav file. I want to add reverberation to that sound. I have seen freeverbreverberation app, but not sure whether i can use that to save the output to file.

Has anybody done this before?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure of how to do this with Matlab itself.  There are software plugins called VSTs, often free, that are used to add reverb to a sound sample, but these usually require a digital audio workstation (DAW) to use.  This is all possible, likely for free, but is quite a bit of overhead depending what you want to do.  I'll advise that making your own "realistic" reverb is probably not a one night programming task.

Comment: Convolve with an appropriate impulse function? You can define such function manually, with many spikes to simulate the reflections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an appropriate impulse response and **convolve** the original sound with it. Each spike in the impulse response represents a reflection of the original sound, and is characterized by its **delay** and **amplitude**. You should define a large amount of spikes, so that they are collectively preceived as reverberation, as opposed to individual echoes.

An **exponential model** is usually employed to represent the decay of amplitude with delay (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation)). You should define **random** values for the parameters so that the reverberation sounds realistic. A simple model is given below.

```
%// Data:
filename = 'file.wav'; %// name of input file. Mono or stereo.
delay_dispersion = .2; %// this defines the amount of reverberation
max_delay = delay_dispersion*4; %// this should be several times the delay dispersion
num_delays = 50; %// number of echoes. Should be large for realistic reverberation

%// Processing:
[x, fs] = audioread(filename); %// read file
delays = round(rand(1,50)*max_delay*fs);
amplitudes = exp(-delays/delay_dispersion/fs); %// exponential profile
amplitudes = .7*amplitudes+.3*rand(size(amplitudes)); %// add some randomness in amplitudes
delays = [1 delays]; %// add clean sound...
amplitudes = [1 amplitudes]; %// ...with unit amplitude
h = zeros(1,ceil(max_delay*fs));
h(delays) = amplitudes;
stem(delays, amplitudes) %// plot impulse response
y = conv2(x,h(:)); %// use conv2 so that it works for mono or stereo x
y = y/max(abs(y(:)));
sound(x(1:min(2*fs,end),:), fs) %// play two seconds of dry sound
pause(2)
sound(y(1:min(2*fs,end),:), fs) %// play two seconds of reverberated sound
```

Possible improvements include applying a **low pass filter** to the delayed replicas, or defining the delays in **clusters** to model reflections from groups of physically close objects.